# Cloning Github Repository with Atom on Gentoo

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, gentoo

So I am trying to set up a new Project I want to work on using Github. Usually, I am working on two different computers, so Github is a convenient choice as a git server.

I recently changed my OS on one machine from Ubuntu to Gentoo.

Now, I use Atom as an editor. And on Ubuntu and my Mac the Github: clone command works without any problems.

Using this with Atom on Gentoo though, I just get the message: 
"Unable to clone ...", nothing more.

I do not even know how to find the problem, as it seems there are no logfiles for Atom?!

The usual command-line git clone ... works.

Atom is the standard portage version 1.23.3.

Comment: does anything show up in the dev console? (control+shift+I and click console tab)

Comment: Nothing that seems interesting: Download the React DevTools and use an HTTP server (instead of a file: URL) for a better development experience: "CANT POST URL" Can't load de_DE: Cannot find dictionary for de_DE.